# Devolver valor más alto con suma

Tags: javascript

No sé si estoy intentando realizar el ejercicio o, directamente, entenderlo. Me piden una función suma pero que devuelva el valor más alto de los dos sumandos, si lo he entendido bien. Lo lógico es que pidiera un resultado, pero no es eso lo que indica el enunciado. ¿A alguien sele ocurre algo?

```
    //Completa la función que tomando dos números como argumento devuelva el más alto.//

function sum(numberOne , numberTwo) {
    
  // insert code
}
```

Comment: Hola, el enunciado (si es el comentario y esta completo) es muy claro, la función debe aceptar dos números como argumentos y **retornar el mayor de ellos**, no dice nada de sumar. Lo que no encaja es el nombre de la función, que es la única referencia a una suma, mi sospecha es que copiaron y pegaron el fragmento de código de otro ejercicio y se olvidaron de modificar la función de forma acorde...

Comment: A mi se me ocurre que compares los dos sumandos que recibe la función y devuelvas el más alto (grande). `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Sinceramente, si tú no entiendes el enunciado (que admito que el nombre de la función no encaja con lo que se pide!) y eres el único aquí que conoce al profesor, cómo vamos a poder entenderlo nosotros? Pregúntale a él! Es su trabajo aclararte cualquier duda